# dockerの差分イメージによるサーバーCI

Tags: docker, jenkins

下記のようなサーバーCIが実現できないか検討しています。

- ステージング環境にて(Docker)
  テスト後、Docker commitを行い、commitしたイメージをsaveまたはexportして
  gitにpush。jenkisで指定ブランチのpushを検知し、本番へDockerイメージを自動デプロイ。

上記で問題になるのがDockerイメージのサイズです。
CircleCIを使用すればDockerイメージの差分だけデプロイさせるような事が
できるそうですが、セキュリティなどの制約によりCircleCIは使用できません。

Jenkinsなどを使用してDockerイメージの差分だけを本番環境などに
オートデプロイさせる事はできないでしょうか？

Dockerイメージの差分の取り方や差分のイメージへの反映などが分かりません。

それらしい事を明記しているWebサイトを一度見た覚えがあるのですが、
ブックマークなど取り忘れ、たどり着けなくなってしまいました。

Comment: DockerイメージはJenkinsではなく手動で作り、そのイメージからJenkinsで差分イメージを作成、本番に転送、といったことを考えておられるのでしょうか？「サーバーCI」と聞いて想像するものは様々でしょうから、具体的に何をどうする方法がわからないのか、タイトルに書いてあるとわかりやすいように思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。Dockerのイメージ差分を取得し、差分のみを反映する方法が不明だった為、その旨を追記しています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dockerの差分イメージというと、layerと言われるもののことかと思います。これはDockerfileの各ステップごと、あるいは `docker commit` を行うことで生成されます。内部的な形式は環境によって異なるため、`docker save` で互換性の高い形式で書き出せるようになっています。

http://tanksuzuki.com/post/docker-image-filesystem/

また、各 layer には固有のIDが振られており、Docker Hubなどの Docker registry に対して `docker push/pull` を行う際はこのIDを元に、転送先にない layer だけを転送するようになっています。

http://enakai00.hatenablog.com/entry/20140802/1406958412

で、CircleCIとDockerを組み合わせたデプロイについては、[CircleCIのドキュメント](https://circleci.com/docs/docker)に記載があり、

- ソースコードリポジトリ上の Dockerfile を使い、`docker build` でイメージ作成、テスト実行
- できあがったイメージを `docker push` で自前の Docker registry に（差分）アップロード
- デプロイ先から `docker pull` を実行し、上記のイメージを（差分）ダウンロード

という手順を踏んでいるようです。

`docker` コマンドだけで差分書き出し・取り込みを行うことも原理上は可能ですが、現状のDockerには実装されていないようなので、Docker registryを用意するとよいかと思います。

Comment: 知りたい事を知る事ができました。丁寧な回答ありがとうございました。